# HTML doesn't load JS files

Tags: javascript, html, webserver

i try to make a simple website with external js and css files.

HTML:

```
<html>


<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <script src="../js/main.js"></script>
  <title> John Doe </title>
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <p>Landing Page in Progress</p>
    <button onclick="clickAlert()">Test</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
function clickAlert() {
    alert("Test")
}
```

Folder structure:

[image: folder_structure]

But when i click the button i get the error *"clickAlert is not defined"*.
Everything is hosted on an Webserver running Ubuntu/Apache.
I know that for this simple function i wouldn't need an external file but i want to expand the site more.
Thanks for every help!

Comment: Open the Network tab in the DevTools, there you can see what is actually loaded, in the Console tab you can see possible error messages for loading too (just make sure you're not filtering out these messages).

Comment: Have you tried the same with Inline JavaScript? Also, Double-check your path. You can see the loaded files in the Browser Developer Tools. Make sure to check the browser console for errors.

Comment: maybe your js file root is not correct.

Comment: it would be easier to help if you also showed an image of the folder structure, most likely it is wrong path in the src

Comment: check and make sure that your js link src is correct :D

Comment: Thanks! The JS folder is not loaded... But how can i get apache to load it? In the sites-available folder i can only point to the root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the js folder in the static folder then put the src as "js/main.js". If the javascript is not included in the static folder, the server doesn't know to put those files on the server.